# Mysql : Left Join and Inner Join in a subquery

Tags: mysql, join

I have 3 tables that i have left joined but I would like to add a field from the table 3 which is inner joined with table 2.

```
Table1
id
name
surname
table2_fk

Table2
id
entry_name
entry_code
table3_fk

Table3
id
type_name
type_desc

SELECT `Name`, `Type Description`
(SELECT
Table1.name AS `Name`,
Table1.surname AS `Surname`,
t2.entry_name AS `Entry`,
t2.entry_code AS `Entry Code`,
t3.type_name AS `Type Name`,
t3.type_desc AS `Type Description`

FROM Table1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON Table1.table2_fk = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON Table2.table3_fk = t3.id
) as subquery
```

My desired outcome is to have t2 inner join t3 and get field from table 1 and table 3

Based on my subquery I would like the `Name` and `Type Description` to show

Comment: Please include sample input and output, so that we don't have to speculate.

Comment: What do you mean? what do you want to achieve

Comment: What's the problem with your query currently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to `INNER JOIN` tables `table2` and `table3` and then `LEFT JOIN` to `table1` then do this:

```
SELECT t1.name, t.type_desc AS `Type Description`
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN (
   SELECT t2.id, t3.type_desc
   FROM table2 AS t2 
   INNER JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.table3_fk = t3.id
) AS t ON t1.table2_fk = t2.id
```

But this could be *perhaps* expressed just as:

```
SELECT t1.name, t3.type_desc AS `Type Description`
FROM Table1 AS t1
LEFT JOIN table2 AS t2 ON t1.table2_fk = t2.id
LEFT JOIN table3 AS t3 ON t2.table3_fk = t3.id
```

Comment: I don't think the second query is the same. What if there's a row in table 2 that matches table 1 but not table 3? Your first query would exclude it, but not your second.

Comment: @shmosel That's correct, the second query *may* return more records in comparison to the first. It depends on the actual data.

Answer (score 1):

I presume you are trying to left join table1 with the result of inner join between table2 and table3

```
select t1.name, t_res.type_desc from table1 t_1 
left join (
   select t_2.id, t_3.type_desc from table2 t_2 
   inner join table3 t_3 on t_2.table3_fk = t_3.id
) as t_res on t_1.table2_fk = t_2.id
```